# Time / Date Recognition with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, date, time

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas, or has stumbled upon a script that will recognize portions of dates and times in any given field of text.

For instance, this sentence right here was being typed at 4:24pm and I suspect I will finish it at about 4:25 or so.. perhaps even later on the 19th.

I would like to be able to make a live listener that will pick out those times above (or guess) and surround them in a link to say... /calendar/events/create/TIMESTAMP

I expect regex could be used to find certain indicators like : or th, or anything like that and take a guess at the rest pending the current time..

Macs do this in mail and icalendar.. pretty cool. Thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wait, what? You want to find times and dates that a user inputted into a text field or do you want to find out the time and date the user started and stopped inputting text?

Comment: It would be a call after the page has loaded.. It would search defined containers for aything... could be in comments or an email from our inhouse webmail client or whatever. Anywhere on the page within a searchable container. It would be a convenience link for users..

So if I got an email and a client mentions a time for a meeting, the   live bind would search the text and replace times with links to a new event, passing a timestamp along to make new event creation faster and more convenient.

Comment: But those types of fragments aren't necessarily dates or times, I mean, I found your 1st and 2nd examples clear, but what if the ratio of non-dates to actual dates was 12:10? A regex could just change them all, but it couldn't determine context for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at **[date.js](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/#Parsing)** library which supports wide variety of formats.

Even with this library you will need to:

- Preprocess the text (like removing dots at the end of sentences, removing whitespaces, ..)
- Filter out false positives (it can parse `th` as `thursday`, `say` as `saturday`, etc).
- Create algorithm for effective scanning of the text.
- Map the found times/dates back to the text, etc.

So there is still a lot of work to do.

To see a very ineffective demonstration of the parsing have a look **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/pFJQD/)**.

Comment: Awesome, yes I expected some work to still be done for adding human decisions. I will have to watch it over time I suppose to continue to better the recognition, but that library is great. Thanks a ton!